# Where I find code for inserting in catalog_product_index_price table?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to find code that helps inserting in magento catalog_product_index_price table. How can I find it or where?

Comment: what is the purpose ?

Comment: I want to see some erors that are making on inserting in that table. And i don't know where they come from.

Comment: Please see this [answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35514/why-does-magento-have-a-stock-index/35518#35518)

Answer (score 1):

The class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price` handles writing to that table. The only method that writes to that table appears to be `_copyIndexDataToMainTable()`.